# How to archive gmails in GS4 stock email app

Tags: email, gmail, samsung-galaxy-s-4

I kind of like the stock email client in Galaxy S4, but I don't use it since I haven't figured out how to set it up to archive mails instead of deleting them.

I subcribe to Google's philosophy "archive, don't delete" but is that possible with stock email client on GS4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I did a more thorough research and found that deleted mails actually **are** archived rather than deleted. What I didn't realize is that deleted mails aren't in fact **moved** to *[imap]/Trash*, they are just labeled like that. So they still are in *All mails* and can be found by browsing or searching. Other labels are also preserved.

This is a feature of Gmail IMAP regardless of the client.

Problem solved - there wasn't any problem in the first place :)

Answer (score 2):

Only Gmail app currently supports archiving for Gmail. Other mail providers do not have the concept of archiving emails, so this is limited only to Gmail and hence to Gmail app alone.

If you want to archive the emails, you should use Gmail app, I see no other workaround.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the stock email app in the GS4 does not support archiving like Gmail app.

So my advice to you is simply use the Gmail app in your GS4 as it offers more and better options than the stock one. Also you can add as many accounts as you want to into it.